# MS Server to Mysql Linked server options vs Web API

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server, webapi

I am working with the Vendor database server. What is good option for sending data to the Vendor server?
POSTing Data to Vendor API is a better or connecting vendor database server(MySql) from MS SQL(My side) server through the Linked Server concept.

Which is more faster and reliable option? My data is a huge size.

Comment: is this a one off transfer or continuous on-going need? Does the vendor need to serve other users besides you? Define "huge size"? What is your fastness requirement?

Comment: 1million in a day on pick hours.

Comment: The things which we requested it is only from my company request. I am not sure that they will sale to another or not...

Comment: How about a CSV export and then a CSV import at the other end.